# I get null when i use find in an array - redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have 3 actions ( add_todo,delete_todo,completed_todo). Add and delete works fine but I should add the deleted items to the completed list in order to render that in a separate component. But whenever I try to use, filter or find to get the deleted items I get a null value.

**Reducer code :**

```
const initialState = {
  todos: [],
  completed: [],
};

const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    add_todo(state, action) {
      state.todos = [...state.todos, action.payload];
    },
    delete_todo(state, action) {
      state.todos = state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    },
    completed_todo(state, action) {
      console.log(state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === action.payload));
      state.completed = [
        ...state.completed,
        state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id === action.payload),
      ];
    },
  },
});

export const todoActions = todoSlice.actions;

export const selectTodo = (state) => state.todos.todos;

export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

**code where i call or dispatch my actions:**

```
function TodoList() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const todos = useSelector(selectTodo);
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    dispatch(todoActions.delete_todo(id));
    dispatch(todoActions.completed_todo(id));
  };
// Some code and a button with handleDelete 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions will be dispatched one after another. After your first action `dispatch(todoActions.delete_todo(id));`, you will remove the todo from your state `.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload)`.

After that, the second action get's dispatched `dispatch(todoActions.completed_todo(id));`. But `state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === action.payload)` will not find it, since it is already removed.

To fix it, you could swap your dispatch calls. First complete it, then remove it. Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is by the time you are dispatching the action to get the completed list your deleted todo's is already gone from the state . Instead of dispatching 2 actions . you can do what are asking for in the `delete todo` action .

```
delete_todo(state, action) {
      // find the todo to delete 
      const deletedTodo = state.todos.find((todo) => todo.id === action.payload);
       state.completed = [
        ...state.completed,
        deletedTodo,
      ];
      state.todos = state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    },
```

since your completed todo is nothing but the todo which you are trying to delete . IMHO its logical to do it in the same action which we use to dispatch for deleting a todo .